# Convergence of double summation series under diagonalization

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, double-sequence

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am stuck at 2.8.7b. The author suggested the strategy in the proof of theorem 2.8.1. But I can't see how the strategy can be deployed. As attached, the proof of theorem 2.8.1 involves 2 variables whereas 2.8.7b involves only 1 variable.

I just don't know how. I can't see how $s_{nn}$ is related in this case. If I tried to minus $d_k$ from $s_{kk}$, it's just another triangle sum.

Comment: Please format the pictures in the question without using links, this makes your question less searchable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see this inequality is a direct implication of squeeze theorem. My question, however, is what if there exists negative terms from $d_n$ to $s_{nn}$, then $d_n>s_{nn}$ may be possible. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Countable I have noticed that the system doesn't allow me to inscribe pictures. Are there any ways other than offering links?

Comment: Its recommended that you TeX them into the question (i.e. "Math Jax").

Comment: You’re right; I wasn’t paying attention. Don’t try to use the $s_{nn}$: imitate the argument instead. Define $t_n$ to be the sum of the absolute values of the terms on the first $n$ diagonals, show that this is a Cauchy sequence, and use that to show that the partial sums of the series $\sum d_k$ are a Cauchy sequence and therefore converge.

Comment: @Countable All of a sudden I received 11 reputation and I am able to embed images now.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I can prove $\sum d_k$ converges. The reason is because I proved $\sum d_k$ converges absolutely in part (a). But I just don't know how does it converge to the same limit as $s_{nn}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @zony_miu: $t_{nn}-t_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor,\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, so if $u_n$ is the sum of the absolute values of the entries on the first $n$ diagonals, then $t_{nn}-u_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. You can use this to show that $\left|s_{nn}-\sum_{k=2}^nd_k\right|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ and hence that the limits are the same.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am sorry but after 2 nights of attempts I still can't infer the correct result. I have several doubts: 1. I am unable to prove $t_{nn}-u_n\rightarrow 0$, I am unable to convince myself the difference is less than $\lvert t_{nn}-t_{\frac{n}{2}\frac{n}{2}}\rvert$; 2. I also fail to infer from $t_{nn}-u_n\rightarrow 0$ to $\left|s_{nn}-\sum_{k=2}^nd_k\right|\to 0$. I am so confused when it involves double summations. I would be extremely grateful if you are willing to elaborate more and include steps. Sorry for my intellectual stupidity.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I will try to answer my question below. Would appreciate a comment.

Comment: @zony_miu: Sorry to be so slow; I had to be out of town most of yesterday and forgot all about it. Yes, that’s basically the idea that I had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $t_{nn}$ converges, it is a Cauchy sequence. Hence,
\begin{align}
\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+\exists n_1\in\mathbb{N}\forall n,m\geq n_1\rightarrow\lvert t_{nn}-t_{mm}\rvert<\epsilon
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+\exists n_1\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\geq 2n_1,\\
\left\lvert\sum_{k=2}^{n} d_k-\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}\right\rvert&\leq\left\lvert\sum_{i,j=2}^{n}\lvert a_{ij}\rvert-\sum_{i,j=2}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\lvert a_{ij}\rvert\right\rvert\text{ (see footnote)}\\
&=\left\lvert t_{nn}-t_{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\right\rvert\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
d_{kk}-s_{nn}\to 0\\
s_{nn}\to\mathbb{S}
\end{align}
By algebraic limit theorem, $d_{kk}\to$ S.

Footnote: This inequality can be visualized as such. $s_{nn}$ is the sum of a square sized with $n^2$ elements. $d_{kk}$ is the sum of elements in the upper left triangle. Hence, the difference of two will be the sum of elements in the lower right triangle. By triangle inequality, they are less than the sum of absolute terms. However, I can't come up with a Cauchy sequence that possesses this property. So I turn to $t_{nn}-t_{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}$, which turns out cover slightly more than the lower right triangle.